# how to find peaks of mit-bih ECG signal in matlab

Tags: matlab

i'm using this code for plotting the ECG signal
http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/matlab/rddata.m
and i want to know how to find the peaks of the ECG signal

Comment: [`findpeaks`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) maybe?

Comment: There is a full example from matlab on how to extract ECG/EKG peaks: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/examples/peak-analysis.html